# Incorrect data being put into database with SQLite

Tags: android, insert, null, sqliteopenhelper

EDIT <<<<<<<<<

I have discovered that the userName retrieved from below is coming back as null. Anyone tell me why?

```
public void getUserName() {

    getUserNameDialog = new Dialog(MasterMindGameActivity.this);

    getUserNameDialog.setContentView(R.layout.retrieveusername);
    getUserNameDialog.setTitle("Enter your Name");
    getUserNameDialog.setCancelable(false);

    TextView viewScore = (TextView) getUserNameDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.showScore);

    viewScore.setText("Your score was " + numberOfGuesses);

    final EditText enterName = (EditText) getUserNameDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.userName);
    btnConfirm = (Button) getUserNameDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.confirmUserName);

    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            userName = enterName.getText().toString();
            getUserNameDialog.cancel();

        }

    });
    getUserNameDialog.show();

}
```

displays something like

```
Highscore
1: null - [correct score]
```

Where [correct score] is the output it should have

Why is the userName not being saved and instead repalced with null?

EDIT 1: FIXED THE DOUBLE SAVE PROBLEM - NOW JUST THE NULL VALUE

Answer (score 1):

You have two insert statements, that is why it is storing twice.

```
 db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);
        long dbcheck = db.insert(HIGHSCORE_TABLE, null, value);
```

Why username is null, you didn't assign getUserName() to userName (see my code below). Safe side I would put System.out right before inserting the data and make sure userName is really getting there.

```
public void saveHighscore() {

    scoreSaved = true;

    userName=getUserName();

    DatabaseOpenHelper database = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    database.addHighscore(userName, numberOfGuesses);

    database.close();

}
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was the place that the userName was being chosen that was actualy, the problem, and it turns out it is. Im going to edit my original question to show where the userName is chosen and hopefully can work out with peoples help from there

Comment: Great! I would suggest instead of editing this, post a new question with updated code, that would be clean. It is upto you.

Comment: I never used DialogBox, but one thing you may try is, inside onclickListener,  userName = v.findViewbyId(R.id.userName).getText().toString();